Where can I find the reference of a story, where Indra's obsession with building a palace taught him a lesson on impermanet nature of material things?
I heard this story in a YouTube video, where a Westerner narrated it. The story is beautiful.
Once Indra was building a grand palace, and he was obsessed with the minor details. He was instructing the divine architect repeatedly. The architect got fed up and showed him a hole from which many ants were coming out. Later he revealed that these ants were previous Indras. Then the current Indra realized the temporary nature of this existence.
What is the source of this story? Please narrate the story from the scripture.

are you looking for this story https://archive.org/details/brahma-vaivarta-purana-all-four-kandas-english-translation/page/372/mode/1up

@CracklingCyclone Yes!!! Thank you so much! You may write it as an answer mentioning the chapter number. I will accept it.

The story of Indra and ants is mentioned in Brahma Vaivarta Purana Krishna Janma Khanda Chapter 47
As per the story once Indra killed Vritasura but was chased by Brahmahatya. So Indra moved to manasarovara, where Brahmahatya cannot enter. At that time, Nahusa became king of Devas and he demanded that Indrani, wife of Indra should  be appointed to serve him. Wife of Indra then reached Tara(wife of Brihaspati) who assured to protect her. Brihaspati then went to Manasarovara and recited the name Madhusudana, and immediately they heard a sound informing to protect from Brahmahatya through Radha-kavacha. Using this Kavacha, Brahmahatya was killed.
Then Brihaspati and Indra went to Amaravati and saw that the city was destroyed by enemy. Indra ordered Vishwakarma to rebuild Amaravati, who then spent one year to build Amaravati. When he finished building, Indra was not satisfied and asked to build even grandly. Since Vishwakarma couldn't return to his adobe before satisfying Indra, he reached Brahma and narrated then whole incident. Brahma then instructed Vishnu to solve the issue. Vishnu then in disguise of a Brahmin boy reached Indra who in turn asked the reason for his visit. Brahmana boy replied that he came to visit the city he built.
When the Brahmana boy saw the city, he said that no Indra in the past have built this much huge city, so he concluded this is the best one. Indra, who didn't know about previous Indras asked him about the same. The Brahmana boy narrated the cyclical nature of creation and about countless number of Trumurtis and Indras and also about innumerable Brahmandas. In the meantime, there was a large group of ants spread over the length of a thousand bows. The boy pointed out the ants and said that they were all Indras in previous yugas and now have taken birth as ants. On seeing this incident, Indra renounced his desire to embellish the city further, presented Vishwakarma with many gifts and allowed Vishwakarma to return to his adobe.
